# How to get data from the last 5 FULL minutes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I write:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date >= NOW - INTERVAL '5 MINTUE';
```

I will get all the data from the last 5 minutes, but the first and last minute won't be full minutes, they'll likely be partial minutes. Meaning if "NOW()" is 4:30:24, then NOW() - INTERVAL '5 MINUTE' will get me from 4:25:24 to 4:30:24. Minute 25 is partial and only contains 36 seconds, same with minute 30 which only contains 24 seconds.

How would I go about getting the last full 5 minutes? I considered removing the first and last minute or min/max, but that idea became a challenge when I consider minute [58, 59, 60, 01, 02]. In this case min/max doesn't account for the cycle back to 0 after minute 60.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date >= date_trunc('minute', now()) - interval '5 minute' and
      date < date_trunc('minute', now())
```

Comment: ahhh... genius! Nice little function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date >= DateADD(mi, -5, Current_TimeStamp)
```